# R data.table using median in i statement

Tags: r, data.table

This is a variation of the question on using the max() function in the i statement for filtering a data.table: [R data.table using max in i statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768702/r-data-table-using-max-in-i-statement/33768782#33768782)

Now I'm trying to figure out how to use the median() function in the same situation. Here's my code that is returning every row:

```
> test_dt <- data.table(value1 = 1:10, value2 = 2:11, value3 = 3:12)
> test_dt[median(c(value1, value2, value3)) < 7]
    value1 value2 value3
 1:      1      2      3
 2:      2      3      4
 3:      3      4      5
 4:      4      5      6
 5:      5      6      7
 6:      6      7      8
 7:      7      8      9
 8:      8      9     10
 9:      9     10     11
10:     10     11     12
```

And here is what I expect to get if the median() function was operating on each row separately:

```
   value1 value2 value3
1:      1      2      3
2:      2      3      4
3:      3      4      5
4:      4      5      6
5:      5      6      7
6:      6      7      8
```

Comment: If you have a numerical data set, working with matrices would probably make more sense. You could do something like `matrixStats::rowMedians(as.matrix(test_dt[, value1:value3, with = FALSE])) < 7` for example in order to find the correct indices.

Comment: @DavidArenburg If you put this as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one. This seems convoluted but it works.

Comment: It's not about convoluted or not, it's about what data structure you are working with. If `test_dt` would have been a matrix already, the solution would have been just `test_dt[rowMedians(test_dt) < 7,]`, is that convoluted? It all depends on the structure of your data and what are you planning to do with it.

Comment: Agreed with David. Data frames are set up to work by column, they're really just lists where each element in a column and each column must have the same length. If you're doing a bunch of row-wise stuff,  a matrix is the way to go. And then if `pmax` and `rowMedians` aren't enough, you can `apply` an arbitrary function to each row.

Comment: From the "*how not to do this department*" - `test_dt[test_dt[,.(sel=do.call(mapply, c(function(...) median(c(...)), .SD)) < 7)][,sel]]`

Comment: Besides, it's not convoluted. Just imagine you already had the object `m = as.matrix(test_dt[, value1:value3, with = FALSE])` (as David meant when suggesting you work with matrices, I think) ... then it's just `rowMedians(m) < 7`

Comment: @thelatemail Now *that's* convoluted!

Comment: When I said, "that is convoluted," it was not meant to be derisive in any way. The solution is just not as straightforward as using pmax() for max by row and therefore appears more convoluted to me, that was all. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Frank didn't I write exactly the same thing in my second comment ? :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oh, so you did. I have trouble reading more than the first sentence of a comment, you see.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an solution using data.table::transpose (twice, so its not *unconvoluted*):

```
test_dt[transpose(transpose(test_dt)[,lapply(.SD,median)])[[1]] <7]
```