# R data.table max of current and all previous rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table named "sampleDT" with column c1 and c2

```
require(data.table)
sampleDT <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3), c2 = c(7,5,6), result = c(NA, 7, 7))
print(sampleDT)
> print(sampleDT)enter code here
   c1 c2 result
1:  1  7     NA
2:  2  5      7
3:  3  6      7
```

I would like to create a new column 'result'; and the value is to take the maximum from previous row:

- 1st row of column 'result' would inevitably be NA;
- 2nd row would give 7;
- 3rd row would also give 7, because `sampleDT[2,result] == 7`.

We can obviously use for-loop to achieve it; I'm wondering if there's any faster solution? (Note: not sure if `shift` would work, because result is dependent on the previous row.

Comment: If you simply want the row-max across both the current and previous row, then yes you could use `shift()`, just take the max across both the current and previous (shift'ed) rows. But when you say "3rd row would also give 7, because `sampleDT[2,result] == 7`", really you can exclude `result` column but either perform infinite row lookback on `c1, c2`, or evaluate this with for-loop.

Comment: maybe `sampleDT[, result := cummax(c2)]; set(sampleDT, 1L, "result", NA)[]`

Comment: Related: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768702/r-data-table-using-max-in-i-statement) using `pmax()`

Comment: The way you phrased this problem I believe this is a simple `cummax`. You are saying for each row, take the maximum of `c2` and `result` from the previous row. However, `result` for the previous row is simply the maximum for all the rows before it (`cummax`). For me at least, the important thing to note here is that the `result` column will NEVER be less than the cumulative max. It also can never be greater, therefore it must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage `data.table`'s chaining:

```
# load package
require(data.table)

# create dummy data
sampleDT <- data.table(c1 = c(1,2,3), c2 = c(7,5,6))

# run code
sampleDT[, result := shift(apply(.SD, 1, max)), 
           .SDcols = 1:2][, result := shift(apply(.SD, 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                            .SDcols = 1:3][]

>
   c1 c2 result
1:  1  7     NA
2:  2  5      7
3:  3  6      7
```